# Can someone explain the flow of execution of spring boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am working on a spring boot application. 
I wanted to know what happens when the application started running and before it becomes ready for user interaction.
I tried going through the console logs but I am still unsure as to what happens when.

Comment: Can you be more specific in question?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should elaborate a bit more your question. That's because you can build different types of applications using Spring Boot. In a nutshell, during the start up the application will basically try to load the "beans" defined in the related context(s), pre-configured components, define the active profile, properties files, etc. Also some Spring and application events are generated during the start up.

A good way to understand what's going on behind the scenes is running the application in **DEBUG** mode. By default, the log level of the application is set as **INFO**.

Have a look at this link for further details:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-application

I hope this can help you as start point.